# Using breadcrumbs with django-filter, QueryDict trouble

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views

I'm using django-filter to drill down and would like to create breadcrumbs for each item that was filtered. For example:

```
Price ranges:
10,000+
5,000-9,999
1,000-4,999
0-999

Bedrooms:
4
3
2
1
```

Each of the items under Price ranges and Bedrooms would be a link to drill down in a queryset.

I'd like to create a breadcrumb such as `Price range 0-999` or `Bedrooms 3` if the user were to click those links, and then show `Price range 0-999 > Bedrooms 3` or `Bedrooms 3 > Price range 0-999` when they click a second link.

The breadcrumbs should maintain order (the part I'm having trouble with) and work for any number of attributes. Clicking a link in the breadcrumb trail should apply the filter clicked on and all filters before it in the trail.

I'd like to create an empty `QueryDict` and then iterate through request.GET to build the `QueryDict` up as I output the breadcrumbs, but for some reason `QueryDict` iterates through its elements backwards (see the documentation).

What's the cleanest way to accomplish this? Does anyone know why `QueryDict` works this way? (I imagine there's a use-case I'm missing.) Any advice is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

keep track of the order in sessions. so when the first filter is clicked (eg 3 beds) store it. then if another one is clicked, build your bread crumbs from sessions. say the second one was 0-999 you'd pull any existing breadcrumbs (in this example you'd find the 3 beds) and then tack on the latest (0-999).